# rack duplicates every log message

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra, rack

When I test a Sinatra app on my local box with rackup, every log message appears twice.  How can I get them to appear only once?

Comment: Could you post your config.ru?

Answer (score 4):

`disable :logging` in your sinatra application.  `rackup` adds the `Rack::CommonLogger` middleware when it starts in the development env (which it does by default).

Comment: But then all the logger is not working. How can we disable the duplication and still keep the logger ability?